# ROS2 action execute callback never exits

Tags: python, action, ros2

I am trying to implement ROS2 action client and server as given in the example repo: https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree... (server.py and client.py). Everything seems working but on the client side 'get_result_callback' is never getting called. On the server side, I am using the following function which does not exit execute callback.

```
async def execute_callback(self, goal_handle):
"""Executes a goal."""
self.get_logger().info('Executing goal...')

# Append the seeds for the Fibonacci sequence
feedback_msg = Fibonacci.Feedback()
feedback_msg.sequence = [0, 1]

# Start executing the action
for i in range(1, goal_handle.request.order):
    if goal_handle.is_cancel_requested:
        goal_handle.canceled()
        self.get_logger().info('Goal canceled')
        return Fibonacci.Result()

    # Update Fibonacci sequence
    feedback_msg.sequence.append(feedback_msg.sequence[i] + feedback_msg.sequence[i-1])
    self.get_logger().info('Publishing feedback: {0}'.format(feedback_msg.sequence))

    # Publish the feedback
    goal_handle.publish_feedback(feedback_msg)

    # Sleep for demonstration purposes
    time.sleep(1)


print('before success')
goal_handle.succeed()
print('after success')

# Populate result message
result = Fibonacci.Result()
result.sequence = feedback_msg.sequence
self.get_logger().info('Returning result: {0}'.format(result.sequence))`
```

Result:

```
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Received goal request 
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Executing goal... 
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1] 
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1, 2] 
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]   
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]   
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13] 
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21] 
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34] 
 [INFO] [minimal_action_server]: Publishing feedback: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55] 
 before success
```

I have not changed anything in the code**

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced :

```
goal_handle.succeed()
```

with

```
goal_handle.set_succeeded()
```

Its working as expected.